# How to disable scrolling in UIScrollView at view with PanGesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

Sorry for my English. It's not my first one.
i have views. Sub view moves at X axis by PanGesture. How to disable PanGesture when collection view or scrollView can scroll to it own edge of content? How to enable PanGesture when scrollView or collectionView is reached it end (example: last cell scrolled at CollectionView and right to left pan gesture has happened)?
[image]

Comment: it seems need to use func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool BUT DidScrol UIScrollViewDelegate calls after shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith

Comment: panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)

Comment: to 季亨达 I added panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
        panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: collectionView.panGestureRecognizer) It's not working

Comment: @Yuri post your code